# On scroll get div to slide down

Tags: jquery

I've got some code that when the user scrolls down and hits that point it will kick off the animation. I want it to slide down but at the moment only slide toggle works - where it opens and closes constantly. How can I get it to just slide down?

```
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.research-revealed').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });

        }

    }); 

});
```

Comment: So I guess you tried to use `slideDown`? What happens if you do that?

Comment: @putvande Yes, doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Note for your previous question: Deleting answered questions gets held against you by Stack Overflow (and by the person that bothered to waste their time answering it) :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once it has reached the desired point, set a flag to indicate that it has animated.

```
var animated = false;

$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.research-revealed').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object && animated == false ){
            animated = true;
            $(this).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
            // Animation complete.
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You should also NOT be binding this to the window scroll event but instead use requestAnimationFrame or throttle the event with an interval. ALSO you should remove the event once your animation has been triggered.

**[Update]** Going further on this...

So here is a combination of modules I use to deal with things like this. I wrote this for the specific purpose of indicating when elements are either in or out of view as well as keeping track of what direction the user is scrolling.

http://codepen.io/jasonhulbert/pen/ZbNoZG

In the JS, you will see one polyfill and two modules. I wouldn't normally include them in the same file as seen here but I just pasted them in and wrapped them in SEAF closures. I typically use them as commonJS modules. The polyfill is for window.requestAnimationFrame and the two modules I created are FrameEvent and InView.

FrameEvent is a simple script I use to manage scroll and resize callbacks that utilize requestAnimationFrame.

InView is what I use to keep track of elements being "in" or "out" of view (the window). As the user scrolls, it will toggle the value of the attribute `data-inview` to either `in` or `out`. It also indicates the scroll direction on the body in the attribute `scroll-direction`. You can also associate callbacks that are fired when the element comes in or out of view (which is helpful in your case).

InView is instantiated like so (this is included at the bottom of the JS):

```
var inview = new InView();
inview.addStage({
    element: '.item'
});
```

Here's all the options you can pass to `.addStage()`:

```
element: 'section', // the element to look for
attr: 'data-inview', // the name of the inview attribute
inVal: 'in', // the value of the attribute when in view
outVal: 'out', // the value of the attribute when out of view
offsetTop: 0, // pixels
offsetBottom: 0, // pixels
delayIn: 0, // in milliseconds
delayOut: 0, // in milliseconds
inCallback: false, // callback when element comes into view
outCallback: false // callback when element goes out of view
```

So, in your case, you could use InView to either (A) apply css properties by using a selector in your css like `.item[data-inview="in"] { //...props }` or (B) set the `inCallback` option to a function that triggers the animation you are currently using. The context of `this` in your callback will be the element.

So, here's that.

```
var inview = InView();
inview.addStage({
    element: '.item', // the element you're looking for
    offsetTop: 100, // wait until the element is 100px within view
    inCallback: function(el) {
       $(el).slideToggle(); // do your animation stuffs
    }
});
```

Even if you don't want to use it, you can check out the `.checkStagePositions` method to see an example of how to calculate where an element is in relation to the window. I know, it's a little cluttered in that function - I need to do some refactoring and pull some of that logic out into separate methods.

Comment: Even though it's set to `display:none;` it's visible from the start and doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

[api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/):

`slideDown() - Description: Display the matched elements with a sliding motion.`

`slideUp() - Description: Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.`

So if you want to hide the element, you have to use `slideUp`. Don`t worry, it will look like it slides down. See this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/98o6cquv/1/)